# Calculator tip why is it not compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hw4Part4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask for the diners’ satisfaction level using these ratings: 1 = Totally
        // satisfied, 2 = Satisfied,
        // 3 = Dissatisfied.
        System.out.println("Satisfacion leve: ");
        int satisfactionNumber = sc.nextInt();

        // Ask for the bill subtotal (not including the tip)
        System.out.println("What is the bill subtotal: ");
        double subtotal = sc.nextInt();

        // Report the satisfaction level and bill total.
        System.out.println("The satisfaction level is: " +
                           satisfactionLevel(satisfactionNumber));

        System.out.println("The bill total is: " +
                           getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal));
    }

    public static String satisfactionLevel(int satisfactionNumber) {

        String satisfactionL = "";

        if (satisfactionNumber == 1) {
          satisfactionL = "Totally-satisfied";
        }

        if (satisfactionNumber == 2) {
          satisfactionL = "Satisfied";
        }
        if (satisfactionNumber == 3) {
          satisfactionL = "Dissatisfied";
        }
        return satisfactionL;
     }

      // This method takes the satisfaction number and returns the percentage of tip
      // to be
      // calculated based on the number.
      // This method will return a value of 0.20, 0.15, or 0.10
    public static double getPercentage(int satisfactionNumber) {

        double getPercentage = 0;
        if (satisfactionNumber == 1) {
          getPercentage = 0.20;
        }
        if (satisfactionNumber == 2) {
          getPercentage = 0.15;
        }
        if (satisfactionNumber == 3) {
          getPercentage = 0.10;
        }
        return getPercentage;
    }

    public static double getBillTotal(double tipPercentage, double subtotal) {

        double totalWithTip =
            (subtotal + (getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
        return totalWithTip;
    }
}
```

Error where it says `getPercentage(satisfactionNumber)*subtotal.....` says `SatisfactionNumber cannot be resolved to a variable`

And in the Main method there is a error on 
`System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal));` I believe it is the related to the last error.

Comment: The error gives you the answer... there's no variable with that name in that scope.

Comment: `satisfactionNumber` is a local variable and `tipPercentage` is a parameter (also local). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: how can I get the getPercentage from method getPercentage on the method getBillTotal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your close. You will need to pass in satisfactionNumber into getBillTotal by adding another parameter. Otherwise it don't know what you are taking about when you say satisfactionNumber. It can't directly see the variables in other functions.

```
public static double getBillTotal(double tipPercentage, double subtotal, int satisfactionNumber) {

    double totalWithTip = (subtotal + (getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
    return totalWithTip;

}
```

Then in your main method call pass it in.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
    System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal, satisfactionNumber));
}
```

And actually you don't need tipPercentage, in fact it's not even defined in main.  Since it can be found by satisfactionNumber you could do this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
    System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(subtotal, satisfactionNumber));
}

...

public static double getBillTotal(double subtotal, int satisfactionNumber) {

    double totalWithTip = (subtotal + (getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
    return totalWithTip;

}
```

OR you could pass in the tipPercentage by calculating it first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
    double tipPercentage = getPercentage(satisfactionNumber);
    System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal));
}

...

public static double getBillTotal(double tipPercentage, double subtotal) {

    double totalWithTip = (subtotal + (tipPercentage * subtotal));
    return totalWithTip;

}
```

Any of these last two would be okay.

Answer (score 2):

In `getBillTotal`, `satisfactionNumber` is undefined, it has meaning within the context of the method.  In order to use it, you would need to define the variable within the context of the method either as a parameter or as a local variable...

In your `main` method, You have the same problem with `tipPercentage`, it's undefined...

Comment: I know I need to call the previous method, I thought I was doing right but I am stuck on this.

Comment: Try calling `getPercentage` before `getBillTotal`...